# php, phpexcel - не стилизует ячейки

Tags: php, phpexcel

Добрый день! Хотел бы задать вопрос. Делаю экспорт в .xls файл из базы через phpexcel. Все нормально выводится, но... Шапка таблицы нормально стилизуется(добавляются границы ячеек, окрашивается текст), но когда я выводу в цикле строки, то они не стилизуются после какой то ячейки.. 
Код примерно такой:

```
$border_right = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'right' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
        ),
    )
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('X5')->applyFromArray($border_right);
```

Может у кого-либо было похожее - как справились?

Comment: а можно код с циклом привести?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!  У вас ячейка X5 случайно не объединена с какой нибудь другой? Если да, то нужно указывать ячейку с которой начинается обледенение. А так вроде бы всегда стилизовалось все хорошо, можете полный код предоставить?